# Android module does not match source code

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle, android-studio-3.0

In my Android Studio Project I use a module as an internal SDK. After upgrading from Gradle 2 to Gradle 3, I just get a decompiled .class file when I `CMD + Click` on a class or function in the app module from the SDK. I want to match the source code of the SDK module with the classes and functions in app.

The module is added to the app gradle with:

```
api project(path: ':app:libs:sdk', configuration: 'default')
```

In settings.gradle it is added with:

```
include :app:libs:sdk
```

Android Studio version: `3.1.3`

Gradle version: `3.1.3`

What I tried so far:

- Clean build
- Invalidate cache / restart
- Removing ./idea and .gradle
- Clean the gradle cache in my home directory

EDIT:

File structure:

```
  - app
    -src
    -libs
      -sdk
```

Comment: do you really need to use `api`? Can you use `implementation project(':sdk')` instead?

Comment: @YosiPramajaya yes it should be `api` because I add code to sdk and it needs to be recompiled.

Comment: Try to use `androidDependencies` gradle command. And you might get the idea from where your project is getting its dependencies.

Comment: @YosiPramajaya yes a compiled aar file is loaded: `:sdk (file: /Users/.../.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/sdk-release.aar/ad316bc56d713b5a03baba34a176455e)` but this should be not the behaviour.

Comment: Somehow it doesnt look like you're having that `:sdk` module in the same project? Can you share with me your project structure, and the `settings.gradle`

Comment: @YosiPramajaya I added the file structure and the updated the settings.gradle and build.gradle